# How to draw this in Android with xml?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to draw in Android XML the form in the image. But so far none of my attempts are successful.  How can I do it?

[image: Arrow]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could define a custom `View` and draw on a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a RelativeLayout you can do a black rectangle and then put a white triangle image over the top. I don't see how you would get a Triangle without the image.

**OK, I must have been a little brain dead yesterday. Here is a better solution.**

The layout:

```
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="300dp"
                  android:layout_height="100dp"
                  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:background="@android:color/black">

       <View android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/background_triangle_right"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

The Drawable that makes the triangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<item>
    <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="87%"
            android:pivotY="140%">
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="10dp"/>
            <solid
                    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Aleady tried, but i can't make the triangle properly.

Comment: You can get away with the cheaper FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout as a slight improvement

Comment: It does not matter what layout you use. The point was to demonstrate the white arrow on top of a view.